# How to access Html.Dropdownlist from separate Jscript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

Is there a way to access a Html.DropdownList from a separate Javascript File?
Bear with me for I am a still a student and have not had much experience yet. I'm learning Asp.Net MVC at the moment and can only find a way to pass strings to scripts.
This is the ajax I'm attempting to move out of my View and into a separate file.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[name=team1],[name=team2]").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePotgPartial", "Teams")',
                data: { team1: $("#team1").val(), team2: $("#team2").val() }
            })
            .done(function (partialViewReturned) {
            $("#potgPartial").html(partialViewReturned)
            })
            .fail(function () {
            alert("Failed");
            });
         });
     });
```

In my view there are two dropdownlists, team1 and team2 of which I need to pass those to my script.

Here's what I have to access my script at the moment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/UpdateDropDown.js"></script>
```

Thanks for any suggestions ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of that code should also work in a separate js file with the exception of this line:

```
url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePotgPartial", "Teams")',
```

In your Javascript part of the view set a variable

```
var updateUrl = '@Url.Action("UpdatePotgPartial", "Teams")';
```

and in your code in the js file use that variable

```
url: updateUrl,
```

Comment: Thank you! It didn't occur to me that you could not use razor inside an external javascript file.